# Dialogflow CX - how to get sys.no-input-1 to repeat instead of going to sys.no-input-default

Tags: dialogflow-cx

[image: 1]

I would like for `sys.no-input-1` no repeat instead of going to `sys.no-input-default` after no input from user for more than one time? How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why not use the sys.no-input-default handler instead then?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the following points for your inquiry and a suggested simpler approach for your use case:

1. If you want to loop **sys.no-input-1**, you can set the Transition Page to  "Current Page" in  the **sys.no-input-1** Event handler. Doing so will make the error loop on the same page when there is repeatedly no input from the user. See below screenshot:

[image]

In addition, you can put responses in the entry dialogue and leave the **sys.no-input-1** response as blank. See sample below:

[image]

If you have an entry dialogue and have responses in your **sys.no-input-1** event, the response will be doubled. See below:

[image]

2. As an alternative simpler solution, you can consider using only **sys.no-input-default** instead as it will automatically ‘loop’ correctly on the same page, without needing a transition page set up. See below for an example:

[image]

This would be a cleaner approach since you will only be using one no-match event handler which is the **sys.no-input-default**. See the Built-in events documentation (https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/handler#event-built-in) for reference.